# Don't understand hsv color palette

Tags: colors, hsv

i test a lot converters hex to hsv rgb to hsv and other options. But don't understand situation i have paint program which i see use HSV palette. i use [TinyColor](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor) converter. I don't know why i sometimes get good color, sometimes not good.

This return good result red color:

```
var color = tinycolor("#FF0000"); //red
color.toHsv(); // return { h: 0, s: 1, v: 1 }
```

This return bad result not yellow color:

```
var color = tinycolor("#FFFF00"); //yellow
color.toHsv(); // return { h: 60, s: 1, v: 1 } and i get not yellow color
```

If i write in my hsv input like this: 
`h: 0.16 
s: 1 
v: 1`

i get yellow collor WTF? 
I see in my HSV palette i can write only one digit numbers like this:

```
1, 0.1, 0.99, max is 1 min is 0.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hue, the h in hsv, is traditionally expressed in degrees around a circle —  the color wheel, which means it can have a value from 0º - 360º. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue

It is sometimes convenient to express this as a percentage instead where 0= 0º, 0.5 = 180º, 1.0 = 360º, etc. The documentation for TinyColor explains that it will accept either input, but it is not clear what its default output is (at least from my quick scan).

It seem to be returning degrees, but your other application is expecting a percentage. A 60º hue **is** yellow, but you may need need to convert to a percentage for whatever application you're using with the hsv palette.

In this particular case, 60º/360º = 0.1667